# C# combining lines in the same text file

Tags: c#

what I have is a text file that is like this:

```
apple|2  
turkey|4  
mango|11  
apple|3  
turkey|4  
mango|4
```

I need the results to be:

```
apple|5  
turkey|8  
mango|15
```

Any tips or suggestions? I know that there is some Math.Abs and such, I'm just not sure how to combine the lines. Any help would be awesome.

Comment: @Steve, if it isn't, it's an incredibly strange application.

Comment: LOL, no it's not homework the file actually has a ton of things, if i see the method for the example above i can make the rest work.

Comment: @Moo-Juice - a shopping list for Thanksgiving in Hawaii perhaps?

Comment: The mango-to-apple ratio is off, I would go with 5:8.

Comment: @RedFilter yeah, but apples are harder to come by in Hawaii, so that would explain the higher mango ratio.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
File.WriteAllLines(
    "test.txt",
    File.ReadLines("test.txt")
        .Select(line => line.Split('|'))
        .Select(tokens => new
        {
            Value = int.Parse(tokens[1]),
            Text = tokens[0]
        })
        .GroupBy(li => li.Text)
        .Select(g => string.Format("{0}|{1}", g.Key, g.Sum(l => l.Value)))
        .ToArray()
);
```

or if you prefer:

```
File.WriteAllLines(
    "test.txt",
    (from lineItem in
        from line in File.ReadLines("test.txt")
        let tokens = line.Split('|')
        select new
        {
            Value = int.Parse(tokens[1]),
            Text = tokens[0]
        }
    group lineItem by lineItem.Text into g
    let sum = g.Sum(x => x.Value)
    select string.Format("{0}|{1}", g.Key, sum)).ToArray()
);
```

Comment: Told you there was a nice way to do it in LINQ.

Answer (score 3):

Untested:

```
var lines = File.ReadLines(sourcePath);
var totals = lines.Select(line => line.Split('|'))
                  .Select(line => new { 
                      Item = line[0],
                      Count = Int32.Parse(line[1]) 
                  })
                  .GroupBy(x => x.Item)
                  .Select(g => new {
                      Item = g.Key,
                      Count = g.Sum(x => x.Count) 
                  });

File.WriteAllLines(
    destinationPath,
    totals.Select(total => String.Format("{0}|{1}", total.Item, total.Count)
);
```

You obviously need to make it more robust, but I am pretty sure that this a. compiles and b. produces the desired results.

Comment: @McKay: Because then it becomes an unreadable morass of code. :-)

Comment: Hehe, I was joking. But in all seriousness, I think Linq in this case makes it harder to make more robust. Error checking in the middle of the linq statements would make things messier.

Answer (score 3):

The LINQ solutions are elegant, but with text files, I prefer a little error checking.

```
string filePath = @"c:\temp\test.txt";
string line; 

Dictionary<string, int> dictAcculumator = new Dictionary<string,int>();

if (File.Exists( filePath ))
{
    using (StreamReader file = new StreamReader( filePath )){
        try
        {
            while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (line.Contains('|')){
                    string[] items = line.Split('|');
                    int count;
                    string item = items[1];
                    if (int.TryParse(items[1], out count)){
                        if (dictAcculumator.ContainsKey(item)){
                            dictAcculumator[items[0]] += count;
                        }
                        else{
                            dictAcculumator.Add(items[0], count);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (file != null)
                file.Close();
        }
    } 
}

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (string key in dictAcculumator.Keys)
{
    //alternatively write to text file
    sb.AppendFormat("{0}|{1}\r\n", key, dictAcculumator[key].ToString());
}

Console.Write(sb.ToString());
```

Comment: Actually any real-life code which works with external input **must** check it for correctness, so your way is the only right way. (Your solution is however missing the reaction on errors, which I would leave as an exercise for the OP.)

Comment: BTW, perhaps you don't need `try`/`finally`, because autodisposing of the `file` at the end of `using` block will close it anyway.

Comment: @vlad.  Good observation on the redundancy of the try / finally.

Answer (score 2):

```
// read the text file
string[] wholeFile;
var values = new Dictionary<string, int>()
foreach (var line in lines)
{
    var pieces = line.Split('|');
    var name = pieces[0];
    var value = int.Parse(pieces[1]);
    if (!values.ContainsKey(name)
    {
        values[name] = 0;
    }

    values[name] = values[name] + value;
}
// spit it back out to a file.
```

I didn't do the file IO nor did I do error checking, but this should get you started.

Answer (score 2):

Create a `Dictionary<string, int>`. Loop through the lines of your text file, split the line at the "|". If there is no dictionary entry for the string, create one. Add the number to the value of the dictionary entry. When you are done looping through the text file, loop through your dictionary and output the results in the desired format.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there's a nice way to do this in LINQ but something like this would work.

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("myfile");

Dictionary<string, int> totals = new Dictionary<string, int>();
foreach (string line in lines)
{
  string[] fields = line.Split(new char[]{'|'});
  if (!totals.ContainsKey(fields[0]))
  {
    totals[fields[0]] = 0;
  }
  totals[fields[0]] += Convert.ToInt32(fields[1]);
}

foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> total in totals)
{
  Console.WriteLine("{0}|{1}", total.Key, total.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by creating a dictionary and iterating over the lines adding to the value if the element exists. I don't have visual studio with me right now, so bare with any potential syntax errors in the following:

```
var linesInFile = File.ReadAllLines("c:\path\to\yourfile.txt");

var dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();

foreach(var line in linesInFile)
{
    var parts = string.Split(new char[] {'|'});
    var item = parts[0];
    var amount = int.Parse(parts[1]);
    if(dict.HasKey(item)){
        dict[item] += amount;
    }else{
        dict.Add(item, amount);
    }
}

foreach(var kvp in dict)
{
     Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}: {1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is tested and works:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Data> items = new List<Data>();
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("C:\\chedberg\\combine.txt"))
        {
            string line;
            string[] split;
            string name;
            int count;
            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                line = reader.ReadLine();
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
                {
                    split = line.Split('|');
                    name = split[0];
                    if(Int32.TryParse(split[1],out count))
                        items.Add(new Data() { Name = name, Count = count });
                }
            }

            List<Data> combinedItems = new List<Data>();
            items.ForEach(item =>
                              {
                                  if (!combinedItems.Exists(combinedItem => combinedItem.Name == item.Name)) 
                                      combinedItems.Add(new Data(){Name = item.Name, Count = item.Count});
                                  else
                                  {
                                      combinedItems.Find(combinedItem => combinedItem.Name == item.Name).Count += item.Count;
                                  }
                              });
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("C:\\chedberg\\combine_out.txt"))
            {
                combinedItems.ForEach(item => writer.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}|{1}",item.Name,item.Count)));
                writer.Flush();
            }
        }
    }

    public class Data
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Count { get; set; }
    }
}
```

}